# EF Core 3 filtering data with Extension method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to make extension method for querying ef core. I have this Extension:

```
 public static class FiltrExtension
  {
     public static IQueryable<Contract> Filtr(this IQueryable<Contract> query, OrderFilter filter) 
     {
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.OrderType))
         query.Where(x => x.OrderType == filter.OrderType);
      return query;
     }
  }
```

and then I am trying to filtr data, but the extension method doing nothing:

```
var data = await _uow.DatabaseContext.Contract.Filtr(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: `query = query.Where(…)`

Answer (score 2):

You should put the result of `query.Where(x => x.OrderType == filter.OrderType);` into `query` like this

```cs
public static class FiltrExtension
  {
     public static IQueryable<Contract> Filtr(this IQueryable<Contract> query, OrderFilter filter) 
     {
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.OrderType))
        query = query.Where(x => x.OrderType == filter.OrderType);
      return query;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the results :

```
public static class FiltrExtension
  {
     public static IQueryable<Contract> Filtr(this IQueryable<Contract> query, OrderFilter filter) 
     {
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.OrderType))
         var result = query.Where(x => x.OrderType == filter.OrderType);
      return result;
     }
  }
```

You can user regular expressions :

```
  public static IQueryable<Contract> And<Contract>(this IQueryable<Contract> source, Expression<Func<Contract, bool>> predicate)
    {   
      return source.Where(predicate);    
    }
```